# Call visual studio modal dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, visual-studio-package

I'm developing some visual studio package projects(vsix) and I need to show a modal dialog box preventing clicks behind it. Something like visual studio About dialog box.

[image]

Clicks behind this dialog are denied while it is being shown.

I did try it using Forms.Form.showDialog but it works only in the vsix context (It prevents clicks in forms of itself and not in visual studio window).

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is remotely even close to right, but check the `Owner` property of your forms in your visx context. If the visual studio window is not the owner of your window then the modalness of the dialog will not propagate through.

Comment: You should use DialogWindow!

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ I will try it and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @ErikEJ post it as an answer please. I works great!!! I will vote in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use DialogWindow as recommended in the VS Design guides